# Backward of torch.argsort()

Tags: python, sorting, pytorch, backpropagation, loss

I want to generate new tensor using output of torch.argsort()

Here is the example code.

```
def reodering (self, x) :

    feature = x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
    weight = self.feature_conv(feature)   
    
    indices = weight.argsort(dim = 1)

    sorted_feature = torch.gather(input=feature, dim=1, index=indices)

    return sorted_feature
```

Where 'x' is a tensor of size (b, c, h, w), self.feature_conv() is 'nn.Conv2d()' and loss is 'MSELoss(sorted_feature, label)'

But when I run this code, the weight of self.feature_conv() is not updated.

And here is my example training code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    ...
    
    model = reodering()
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)
    
    ...

    #--------------------
    # training
    #--------------------
    for epoch in range(args.num_epochs):
        model.train()
        
        for i, data in enumerate(inputs_set, start = 1) :
            inputs = np.load(os.path.join(inputs_path, data))
            labels = np.load(os.path.join(labels_path, data))
            inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs).to(device)
            labels = torch.from_numpy(labels).to(device)

            preds = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(preds, labels)

            optimizer.zero_grad()                
            loss.backward()                    
            optimizer.step()

    ...
```

This code only imports important codes.
Where input and label is An image tensor patched to 17x17.

I know that 'torch.long' is not support 'backward' in Pytorch.
I tried changing torch.gather()`s input to weight and it worked fine.
However I want to reorder the 'feature'

Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you show the call to `reodering` and the backward call?

Comment: Oh I`m sorry. I just edited my post.